# Использование общего словаря в классе

Tags: python, классы

Не могу понять причину не накопления данных в словаре

```
class CLASS_A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.classDict = {
            'a': 'aaaa',
            'b': '',
        }

class CLASS_B(CLASS_A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def funkB(self):
        print(self.classDict)
        self.classDict['b'] = 'bbbb'
        print(self.classDict)

class CLASS_C(CLASS_B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def funkC(self):
        print(self.classDict)
        self.classDict.update({'c': 'cccc'})
        print(self.classDict)


tB = CLASS_B()
tB.funkB()
tC = CLASS_C()
tC.funkC()
```

Ожидается, что словарь classDict будет наполняться и в результате получу:

```
...
{'a': 'aaaa', 'b': 'bbbb', 'c': 'cccc'}
```

Но в реальности получаю такой вывод:

```
{'a': 'aaaa', 'b': ''}
{'a': 'aaaa', 'b': 'bbbb'}
{'a': 'aaaa', 'b': ''}
{'a': 'aaaa', 'b': '', 'c': 'cccc'}
```

Как правильно накапливать данные в словаре?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Классовые переменные объявляются  вне блока `__init__` и без `self`:

```
class CLASS_A:
    classDict = {
        'a': 'aaaa',
        'b': '',
    }
```

2. Код уже будет рабочий, но все изменения отражаются и в `CLASS_B.classDict` и в `CLASS_A.classDict`, поскольку это один и тот же объект. Если нужна независимость, то нужно *пересоздать* словарь в классе `CLASS_B`. И абстолютно также сделать в классе `CLASS_C`:

```
class CLASS_B(CLASS_A):
    classDict = dict(CLASS_A.classDict)
    #...
class CLASS_C(CLASS_B):
    classDict = dict(CLASS_B.classDict)
    #...
```